# WP Query, latest posts doesnt show

Tags: php, wordpress

Im experiencing something a bit weird - I have a custom query that should display the latest posts from all categories, however, it doesn't :(

```
<?php
     $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '5'
    );
    $customQuery = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

However, if i manually define which category id's it should display from, it works?
Why? And should it work fine without me having to define the category id's manually?

```
<?php
     $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
        'cat' => array(1, 2, 189, 520) //It works if I add id's from all categories
    );
    $customQuery = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Comment: When you say it "*should display the latest posts from all categories, however, it doesn't*"... what *does* it do? We can't fix errant behaviour when we don't know what that behaviour is :)

Comment: I've created 2 new posts, but they arent showing, however, it displays a post added 2 weeks ago... All posts are assigned to categories

Comment: Cant really explain it otherwise... Seems like it just doesnt show the new posts created, unless a specify all categories in cat => array(ids)

Comment: Are all the posts in question published and public, or are some in draft, pending, private, etc?

Comment: Even knowing it doesn't show the 2 new posts but shows the other s helps :) "Not working" could mean anything from showing in the wrong order to an error message. Do you have any filters in your functions.php that might be setting / resetting the categories or changing your queries in some other way?

Comment: All are published, and there isn't any filters in the functions.php
It's a baseline from https://underscores.me/

Comment: If you don't order by date, does that make a difference? Maybe the date on the new posts is incorrect. How about any plugins? They could be interfering with the query too. If not, I suggest going back to one of the default WP themes (e.g. twentytwenty) and adding nothing but your query. Where is this query being added?

Comment: Ahhhh, finally found the issue... I had a plugin enabled that somehow was conflicting.. Disablling the plugin, helped :)